# How to center an image using Showdown

Tags: showdown

Is there a way to center an image using ShowDown.

I am trying something like this:

```
## Next line has an image

![image](http://i.imgur.com/wYTCtRu.jpg =50%x50% )
```

Answer (score 2):

To style a specific image in shodown, [you can use the title attribute](http://showdownjs.github.io/demo/#/%3Cstyle%3E%0Aimg%5Btitle%3D%22myImage%22%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20border-radius%3A50%25%3B%0A%7D%0A%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%0A%23%23%20Next%20line%20has%20an%20image%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A!%5Bimage%5D(http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FwYTCtRu.jpg%20%3D50%25x50%25%20%22myImage%22)).

The problem is that "centering" requires a parent element to "center" against. So you will always need to add a "wrapper".

To accomplish that, you have a couple of options:

1. use [HTML and CSS](http://showdownjs.github.io/demo/#/%23%23%20Next%20line%20has%20an%20image%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FwYTCtRu.jpg%22%20width%3D%2250%25%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%0A---%0A%0A%23%23%20Next%20line%20has%20an%20image%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3Cdiv%20markdown%3D%221%22%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E!%5Bimage%5D(http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FwYTCtRu.jpg%20%3D50%25x50%25)%3C%2Fdiv%3E) (click the 3 bar symbol in the upper-left corner to close the options menu)

   ```
   ## Next line has an image

   <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wYTCtRu.jpg" width="50%"></div>
   ```

   **or**

   ```
   ## Next line has an image

   <div markdown="1" style="text-align: center;">![image](http://i.imgur.com/wYTCtRu.jpg =50%x50%)</div>
   ```
2. use [the `<center>` html tag](http://showdownjs.github.io/demo/#/%23%23%20Next%20line%20has%20an%20image%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3Ccenter%3E!%5Bimage%5D(http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FwYTCtRu.jpg%20%3D50%25x50%25%20%22myImage%22)%3C%2Fcenter%3E) (deprecated in HTML5)

   ```
   ## Next line has an image

   <center>![image](http://i.imgur.com/wYTCtRu.jpg =50%x50%)</center>
   ```
3. [wrap the image tag in a `<a>` tag and style with CSS](http://showdownjs.github.io/demo/#/%3Cstyle%3E%0Aa%5Btitle%3D%22myImageWrapper%22%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20display%3A%20block%3B%0A%20%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%0A%20%20text-align%3A%20center%3B%0A%7D%0A%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%0A%23%23%20Next%20line%20has%20an%20image%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%5B!%5Bimage%5D(http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FwYTCtRu.jpg%20%3D50%25x50%25)%5D(%23%20%22myImageWrapper%22))

   ```
   <style>
     a[title="myImageWrapper"] {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
   }
   </style>

   ## Next line has an image

   [![image](http://i.imgur.com/wYTCtRu.jpg =50%x50%)](# "myImageWrapper")
   ```